# How to copy from zip in the pipe into postgresql table without psql console?

Tags: postgresql, copy, pipe

In the psql console works the following statment:

```
\copy fcd_in ("column_1", "column_2", "column_3") FROM PROGRAM 'unzip -p c:\tmp\tmp.zip' WITH DELIMITER AS ';' NULL as 'null' CSV header;
```

In DBeaver i get for the same statment:

```
copy fcd_in ("column_1", "column_2", "column_3") FROM PROGRAM 'unzip -p c:\tmp\tmp.zip' WITH DELIMITER AS ';' NULL as 'null' CSV header;
```

SQL-Fehler [38000]: FEHLER: Programm »unzip -p c:\tmp\los\los_HERES201R2.zip« fehlgeschlagen
Detail: Kindprozess hat mit Code 1 beendet

Comment: It is not the same statement `\copy` != `COPY`. `\copy` is a client command that runs as the client user. `COPY` is a server command that runs as the server user. Best guess is you are running into permissions issues when running as the server user.

Comment: i find the bug unzip is not in the system variable maybe with the explizit path for unzip works also in dbeaver

Answer (score 1):

With `\copy`, `PROGRAM` refers to a program on the client machine, while with `COPY` it refers to a program on the database server machine. That explains the different behavior.